# Join query failing in Informatica SQL transformation

Tags: sql, db2, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a SQL query to which am passing parameters from expression transformation:

Eg:

```
  SELECT A.id 
  FROM table1 A, table2 B
  WHERE A.id = B.id
```

This works fine and am able to get the output.

Now when I modify this sql to :

```
select DR.id from(select A.id from table1 A, table2 B where A.id = B.id)DR 
left outer join table3 C on Dr.id = c.col1
```

Then it throws  ODL Error -

> ERROR  TRANSF_1_1_1_1  pmsql_50065 [ERROR] ODL error: 
>        FnName: Bind Parameter -- [Informatica][ODBC PWX Driver] PWX-00264 DBAPI Error Initial "Describe" CONVERSE failed to location ,;DSNT408I SQLCODE = -199, ERROR:  ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD LEFT.  TOKEN , FROM; 
>        INTO WAS EXPECTED;DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42601 ;DSNT415I SQLERRP    = DSNHPARS ;DSNT416I SQLERRD    = 2  0  0  -1  129  506 ; Database driver error...
>        parameter binding failed.

The sql query when executed from sql assistant works fine. So could you suggest as how to write query in Informatica SQL transformation.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the query with parameters you have used in the SQL transformation.

Answer (score 1):

there is no column in your sub-query DR name 'col1' so make it 1st then use it

```
select DR.col1 
from
(select A.id as col1 from table1 A join table2 B on 
A.id = B.id
) DR 
left outer join table3 C on Dr.col1 = c.col1
```

Comment: Col1 in Dr is nothing but the Dr.id...I have formatted my SQL....On using this left outer join its doesn't work

Comment: How you feel it does not work? Does it return any data?  Or not your expected data?

Comment: It returns nothing...the file is blank...when I open session logs I see the above posted error message

Comment: Execute that query on db and check what returns